# html to pdf with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

The html is pretty simple with just an image and an absolutely positioned div.
The pdf looks good, the layout is perfect and the resolution too but there's one extra blank page.

I tried these two commands and I get the same result:

```
wkhtmltopdf --page-width 11 --page-height 8.5 -O Landscape file.html file.pdf
wkhtmltopdf -s Letter -O Landscape file.html file.pdf
```

How can I get rid of the blank page?

Comment: What's in `file.html`? If you can, reduce it to the bare minimum where the problem still occurs.

Comment: I fixed it by using position: absolute on the image too. Z-index values work as expected.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what was the fix? changed command or the html file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it by using `position: absolute` on the image too. `z-index` values work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Check once more your css for extra div which set the height property .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probleme and fixed it by removing the style "display:table" on the style of a div (the main container div).